# Firefox 67.0.4 bookmark list problems

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

I just upgraded to the latest firefox under 16.04.  The drop-down bookmark list seems to have lost functionality:

1. I can no longer get focus by typing the first initial of a bookmark;
2. Neither the keyboard cmd nor the right mouse button bring up the menu which gives access to properties and allows deletion

Comment: What was the previous version?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that I had to download the version from Mozilla instead of using the repository; that required copying the extracted directory to /opt/firefox67.0.4, and creating a new symbolic link in usr/bin/firefox to /opt/firefox67.0.4/firefox.  
The new version would not recognize my existing profile; if I tried to use the existing profile, Firefox would refuse to load.  I finally had to copy places.sqlite to the new profile, then reinstall my add-ons.